# workflow not working in the Globi flow Citrix Podio

Tags: php, podio

There is an invoice app in podio and data is coming from that app and we are printing that data through a php code loop which is not working correctly.The main error is that this loop is not working to print description and amount. Below is the screenshot so please help me in it.
[image]

Comment: You mentioned there's a problem with some PHP code, but I don't see any PHP code here. We can't help you with code we cannot see. All we see is what appears to be Podio's low-code flow-builder. At a guess maybe one or two of the functions used within it bear some resemblance, or make use of, some core PHP functions behind the scenes, but certainly it isn't valid, standard PHP syntax.

Comment: Also "not working" is not an adequate problem description. It tells us nothing useful. Explain exactly what you expected the code to do, and what exactly it does instead. Then explain what debugging you've done so far, what you've tried in order to attempt to resolve it, and where precisely you're stuck.

Comment: Please also read [ask], how to make a [mre] of your issue and - in this case - [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Code and data is text. Provide it as text, please. Images are helpful as secondary illustrations of an issue, but they are not searchable, copyable, re-usable etc. This makes it a lot harder for people to help you, and for others with similar issues to find your question. Thanks.